# What is the purpose of this 4-pin interface on SATA HDDs and why doesn't it exist on SSDs?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I have 4 HDDs here with me, from 3 different manufacturers, and all of them have the following 4-pin extra interface beside the SATA connector:

HDD with 4-pin interface

[image: HDD with 4-pin interface]

Looking on the internet, I can see that it exists on all HDD devices, but not on SSDs:

SSD without 4-pin interface

[image: SSD without 4-pin interface]

On old IDE devices, there was a similar interface used to select operational mode (master/slave), but on SATA it doesn't make sense anymore.

Could someone tell me what this interface is intended to do and why it doesn't exist on SSDs? It is used in any practical situations?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Those are jumper settings, similar to the IDE drives you mention, but for SATA specific options depending on the drive maker. For example, on this [Western Digital support page](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/981/p/227,194/c/123/session/L3RpbWUvMTM0MDczMjIxNC9zaWQvSmVBZVFFX2s%3D#satamobilejump) for mobile drives, it shows two options:

- [Reduced Power Spinup](http://www.wdc.com/en/library/portable/2579-001116.pdf) - RPS: Used by external hard disks to reduce spinup current and allows it to work over USB interface.
- [Spread Spectrum Clocking](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1291/~/a-description-of-spread-spectrum-clocking-for-wd-sata-drives) - SSC: Used when your SATA controller doesn't support SSC by default.

[image]

Also, it doesn't exists on SSDs because there is no spinup or spread spectrum related to solid-state devices.

@Adrian Cox mentions in the comments below, a different pin function for Seagate drives.

Comment: *> RPS: Used by external hard disks to reduce spinup current and allows it to work over USB interface.*   I am going to punch you! Why didn't you post this a couple of months ago, *before* I rigged a SATA drive with a DIY-external-drive setup (eBay cable and power adapter)? Maybe then it would not have (literally) burned out the PCB. `:-(` +1 for both answering the question and enlightening me on about RPS.

Comment: Why would you ever *not* want reduced power spin up though?

Comment: Presumably its lower performance than the full power spin up. I wouldn't be surprised if the drive ran at a slower RPM as well.

Comment: @KayEss fast boot time

Comment: @ratchetfreak actually reducing power spinup will increase boot time in something like 0,5s....

Comment: @kayEss As USB ports are designed to work with 500mA max, if you start a HDD with 1A it will burn...

Comment: You should probably emphasise that the jumpers are manufacturer specific. For instance, Seagate have the same four pin connector, but with a different function: http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/193991en

Comment: @Diogo For some people, racing matters.  And even if you want to say that the amount of time is negligible, the amount of power difference might also be small.  So the trade-off may be worthwhile.  Another possibility is that a slower spin-up means it takes longer to get to operational speed, causing more wear and tear before the device is really becomes useful.

Comment: @Diogo - I sincerely hope that the majority of modern PC's have current limiting on their USB ports, so by not reducing spinup speed, ergo initial current draw, the effect should simply be that the HDD appears to be dead to the naked eye upon trying to spinup. As an aside for all, this is why many external cables/enclosures have a cable that breaks out to 2 USB A plugs, to draw 500mA per USB port, to allow up to 1A draw.

Comment: Oh god, I thouught my SSD was incompatible, because of those extra pins, but those are just jumper pins, thankfully

Comment: Seagate moved their page from @AdrianCox answer. wayback has it though https://web.archive.org/web/20160608230214/http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/193991en

Answer (score 5):

According to what i can find its a Manufacture specific firmware terminal that aids in HDD recovery. [PC USB Terminal adapter](http://www.acelaboratory.com/pc3000.udma.php) There's a few images on this particular page that shows how to connect a USB cable to those ports using Manufacture specific adapters.

Answer (score -1):

That's a temperature port compatible for imac

Comment: Although this might be a right response, but this is not the right answer.