# Doing some detective work on old computer hardware

Tags: console, computer-architecture

On a recent holiday to Bangkok, I visited the science museum and planetarium that is there. While eating lunch I was very surprised to see some very recognisable vintage computer equipment in almost open-air storage (sadly they are all slowly rotting away slowly). I managed to get some photos, I wish I had time to get more, but I was in a no-public area! I've identified some of the equipment, but I really appreciate the rest of the equipment being identified, for the sake of my classroom wall! I suspect that some of the smaller machines may day back to the 1940's (or maybe earlier).

Can you help in identifying any of these?

1. That's me with this collection of dinosaurs!
   [image: That's me with this collection of dinosaurs!]
2. The whole kit and
   [image: The whole kit and kaboodle]
3. UNIVAC 1710 Verifying Interpreting Punch 
   [image: UNIVAC 1710 Verifying Interpreting Punch]
4. IBM 1402 Reader/Punch 
   [image: IBM 1402 Reader/Punch]
5. IBM 1403 Line Printer 
   [image: IBM 1403 Line Printer]
6. A rear view showing various devices 
   [image: A rear view showing various devices]
7. UNIVAC UNISERVO VI-C 
   [image: UNIVAC UNISERVO VI-C]
8. Any clues on what this might be? 
   [image: Any clues on what this might be?]
9. Any clues on this lot? Especially the big devices underneath? The keyboards might belong to a Raytheon PTS-100 of which there seems to be several (another photo) 
   [image: Any clues on this lot? Especially the big devices underneath? The keyboards might belong to a Raytheon PTS-100 of which there seems to be several (another photo)]
10. Raytheon PTS-100, there are several of these or similar machines 
    [image: Raytheon PTS-100, there are several of these or similar machines]
11. Any clues on any of these? 
    [image: Any clues on any of these?]
12. This one has really got my curiosity. Any clues? I suspect it might be wartime or earlier.
    [image: This one has really got my curiosity. Any clues?]
13. A super-slow(!) Racal-Milgo Omnimode 96
    [image: A super-slow Racal-Milgo Omnimode 96]
14. This is my wall display, I'm linking the hardware I've photographed to information found on the internet about those devices and with better photos.
    [image: My classroom wall display]

Comment: That was some high tech in the days.

Comment: It sure was. I'm so excited to having seen this stuff first hand, it's given me something I can put up on my classroom wall as a history display. Hoping to add some real hardware to that display. I've got a first generation iBook, but hoping to get some earlier stuff, like a Commodore Vic-20 or 64, or anything else of that generation.

Comment: In Photo 9, those big devices underneath with the blue front, seem to be IBM's based on the colour scheme, looking at this page of an IBM 1440 system I'm wondering if these are tape processing units similar to those show in the photo: http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/mainframe/stoprun/Stop-Run/1440/

Comment: Just identified the device in Photo 12 - it's a Teletype, possibily a Model 19, but the one in this webpage has a gauge of some kind, whereas the one I photographed does not: www.radioblvd.com/rtty_teletype.htm - any clues? Is it a variation of the Model 19, or something different?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because (I believe) it qualifies as a “Guessing Game”-type question -- see [Let’s Play The Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game) and [Are “Guessing Game” type questions allowed on SU?](http://meta.superuser.com/a/6074/150988)

Comment: As cool as this is, Scott is correct.

Comment: I disagree, this is legitimate research I am doing for the benefit of my computer /I.T. classes

Comment: I agree with @DavidA.Moody this question does not stray away the scope of the site. we have had similar questions in the past where people showed us pics of h/w they could not identify.e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/441817/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-4-pin-interface-on-sata-hdds-and-why-doesnt-it-exis